# How could I implement art similar to the Gwent cards?

Tags: graphics

Here is an example of the Gwent artwork when moving the card around: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSFja.jpg

What is the most likely way this has been implemented? Is it a 3D model or is it just many layers of 2D art? But then, what about the jiggling?

The character seems to look correct from all perspectives, with body parts closer to the camera properly occluding the parts behind them. This makes me think it is simply a 3D model but it looks incredibly 2D as well.

Answer (score -1):

To me it looks like an orthographic projected 3D figure with baked lights on a parallax 2D image.

The deadly man in the front looks like a sprite too, it doesn't have any depth, that's why the girl seems to be comming out the card.

There's also some kind of reflection applied on the main figure, but I would say it's the only "light direction reactive" element in the scene.

So, summarizing:

2D background

3D figure

Baked lights and shadows

little reflaction effects in the figure

2D dead man in the front

EDIT: the dead man has 2 layers, one for the legs and one for the rest of it